# Whats wrong with the following JIRA Jelly + Soap Script?

Tags: soap, wsdl, jira, jelly

anyone knows what wrong with the following Jira,  Jelly + Soap script?
Assume the WSDL file is correct, since it works with soap directly.

```
    <JiraJelly xmlns:jira="jelly:com.atlassian.jira.jelly.enterprise.JiraTagLib" xmlns:core="jelly:core" xmlns:soap="jelly:soap">
<core:new var="endpointvar" className="java.lang.String">
    <core:arg type="java.lang.String" value="http://somehost:9080/newWSDLService/newWSDLPort"/>
</core:new>
<core:new var="Saction" className="java.lang.String">
    <core:arg type="java.lang.String" value="POST http://somehost:9080/newWSDLService/newWSDLPort HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: ''
User-Agent: Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1
Host: somehost:9080
Content-Length: 308"/>
</core:new>
<soap:invokeRaw endpoint="${endpointvar}" soapAction="${Saction}" var="answer">
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:new="http://j2ee.netbeans.org/wsdl/BpelModuleJira/newWSDL">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <new:newWSDLOperation>
             <part1>Hello</part1>
          </new:newWSDLOperation>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
</soap:invokeRaw>
</JiraJelly>
```

Comment: What is this, a pub quiz? What happens when you try it?

Comment: Oh, sorry about that.
It just echoes the same output back to me.  No log file, No results, nothing.
Maybe something wrong in the syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Look in all the logs, The JellyRunner occaisionally drops error messages in strange places.
2. As an aside: thats a seriously weird way to initialize Strings. Try:

<core:set var="endpointvar">http://somehost:9080/newWSDLService/newWSDLPort</core:set>

Comment: Thanks for answering!  Im sorry but the problem is not accessible anymore (we went a completely different way).  But from what I learned from this experience is: avoid Jelly by all means.  Jelly is probably the hardest way to resolve any problem.  This blog post, http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2004/6/10/jelly-scripting-for-the-soulless, gives some good points why to avoid jelly.  Using Jelly + SOAP was just nuts.  Your answer seems reasonable, probably I didn't find the logs (I was inexperience and all).  For the curious, I ended up creating a plugging for JIRA instead of going the Jelly way.